# How to create stored procedure with if else condition?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Now I'm working in xampp. So there I make database for one project, now I'm facing a problem. That is when I create a stored procedure with if-else condition there stored procedure is not created some errors are arising.

I explain here all the problem:

I have one table of admission_students. So in this we store name, sex and village, distt, and town and some other info.

Now I want to create a stored procedure where we get the data from users. so on the frontend user have  choice to enter some fields like sex, village or distt.

Now I want if user enter only sex. then in the I want to create a stored procedure with if condition where we see if sex in not null or in sex field have some value then search on the base of sex. or like these condition.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using a view as oppose to stored procedure. Anyway, please post your code on what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Now i attached a image so pls explain to me

Comment: Don't give parameters and declared variables the same names.And what does your call statement look like?